# Regex validation capability in VBA Word 2010

Tags: regex, vba, office-2010, word-2010

I need to check if a textbox only contains whole numbers plus `-` and `,`.  Where `-` and `,` must only exist in between numbers, i.e. they must never exist at the end or at the starting.

The following would be valid

```
1-5,45,23,4,100-110
```

The following would be invalid

```
,1-4
-5-1,4
```

Can regex be used for such validation?

Comment: What if the user inputs invalid ranges like `10-5`? Regexes can't catch these cases.

Comment: I didn't think of that!  That would be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
^\d+(?:-\d+)?(?:,\d+(?:-\d+)?)*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^          # Start of string  
\d+        # Match a number.
(?:-\d+)?  # Optionally match a dash and a number
(?:        # Match the following group:
 ,         #  a comma
 \d+       #  and a number
 (?:-\d+)? #  (or a range, as above)
)*         # any number of times, including zero.
$          # End of string
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex should do:

```
^(\d+(?:[-,]\d+)*)$
```

[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dW6aQ7)

Comment: This also matches `1-2-3-4`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker it should match, isn't?

Comment: I doubt it (although the question doesn't explicitly forbid this) - it looks like the OP wants to validate page ranges, like in a print dialog.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, your assumption is correct about the print dialog's page ranges.